# Finding number of weeks between dates Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle

If I have 2 tables:

members:

```
CREATE TABLE members
(member_id number,
lastname varchar2(10),
firstname varchar2(10),
license# number(9),
ST char(2),
credit_card number(12));

INSERT INTO members VALUES(10, 'Tangier', 'Tim', 111111111, 'VA', 123456789111);
INSERT INTO members VALUES(12, 'Maulder', 'Fox', 333333333, 'FL', 333333333333);
INSERT INTO members VALUES(13, 'Wild', 'Coyote', 444444444, 'VA', 444444444444);
INSERT INTO members VALUES(14, 'Joan', 'Casteel', 555555555, 'FL', 555555555555);
```

and rental:

```
CREATE TABLE rental
(rental_id number(2),
rent_date date,
return_date date,
pay_method varchar2(10),
movie_id number,
member_id number);

INSERT INTO rental VALUES(1, '18-SEP-09', '1-OCT-09', 'Credit', 11, 10);
INSERT INTO rental VALUES(2, '18-SEP-09', '3-OCT-09', 'Credit', 8, 10);
INSERT INTO rental VALUES(3, '11-OCT-09', '19-OCT-09', 'Check', 6, 12);
INSERT INTO rental VALUES(4, '28-OCT-09', '31-OCT-09', 'Debit', 3, 13);
INSERT INTO rental VALUES(5, '28-OCT-09', '5-NOV-09', 'Debit', 5, 13);
INSERT INTO rental VALUES(6, '29-OCT-09', '11-NOV-09', 'Debit', 11, 13);
INSERT INTO rental VALUES(7, '1-NOV-09', '11-NOV-09', 'Credit', 10, 14);
INSERT INTO rental VALUES(8, '2-NOV-09', '10-NOV-09', 'Credit', 12, 14);
INSERT INTO rental VALUES(9, '5-NOV-09', NULL, 'Cash', 4, 12);
INSERT INTO rental VALUES(10, '8-NOV-09', '18-NOV-09', 'Cash', 12, 12);
INSERT INTO rental VALUES(11, '14-NOV-09', NULL, 'Cash', 3, 12);
INSERT INTO rental VALUES(12, '18-NOV-09', NULL, 'Debit', 11, 13);
```

How can I display the number of weeks between the rent date and return date? If NULL then the return date is set to 'Dec 1, 2009' in a new column called 'delay_weeks' which should be rounded to integers. Then also a new column named 'Status' which shows if each transaction has been returned or not.

This is for a homework question but I can't seem to get it right. We are supposed to only use 1 SQL statement.

So far I have tried the following, which I think is almost correct however I get the error: "MEM"."RENTAL_ID": invalid identifier.

```
SELECT mem.member_id AS member_id, 
       ren.rental_id AS rental_transaction_id,
       case
       when ren.return_date IS NULL
       THEN ROUND(TO_DATE('01-dec-2009','dd-mm-yyyy')-TO_DATE(ren.rent_date, 'dd-mm-yyyy')) 
       ELSE ROUND(TO_DATE(ren.return_date, 'dd-mm-yyyy')-TO_DATE(ren.rent_date, 'dd-mm-yyyy'))
       END AS delay_weeks, 
       CASE
       WHEN ren.return_date IS NULL
       THEN 'not return'
       ELSE 'return'
       END AS status
FROM   members mem
       JOIN rental ren ON mem.member_id = ren.member_id
order BY member_id;
```

Any guidance on this would be appreciated. Please let me know if any clarification is needed. TIA.

Comment: `mem` is alias for table `members`. That table does not have a column `rental_id`. What is unclear in the error message? If you can't find ***where*** you have that, it's (at least) in the join condition at the end. Can't join on a column that doesn't exist in **both** tables.

Comment: `TO_DATE('01-dec-09','dd-mm-yyyy')` will return 1st December 0009 AD. If you are going to require 4-digit years in the format mask then you should supply them in the input.

Comment: @mathguy I changed it to mem.member_id = ren.member_id, it runs with no error however the output is blank

Answer (score 0):

You can subtract the dates, providing a `'Dec 1, 2009'` date in place of `NULL` `return_date`s, then divide by seven:

```
select m.member_id, r.rental_id, floor(((case when r.return_date is null then to_date('01-DEC-09') else r.return_date end) - r.rent_date)/7) weeks
from rental r join members m on r.member_id = m.member_id;
```

Comment: Don't rely on implicit format models. If you are going to use `TO_DATE` then explicitly state the format model (and, if you are using language specific strings, the `NLS_DATE_LANGAGE` as well). `TO_DATE('01-DEC-09', 'DD-MON-RR', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English')` [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=811faf8db8b0532fec07967fa8c3c547)

Answer (score 0):

Don't call `TO_DATE` on a value that is already a date; if you fix that then you get then code:

```
case
when ren.return_date IS NULL
THEN ROUND(TO_DATE('01-dec-09','dd-mm-yyyy')-ren.rent_date) 
ELSE ROUND(ren.return_date-ren.rent_date)
END AS delay_weeks,
```

If you run that then it highlights the next issue that `TO_DATE('01-dec-09','dd-mm-yyyy')` expects a 4-digit year but you have only provided a 2-digit year so you will get the year 9 AD rather than 2009 AD (and differences of around `-730461` days). The best solution is to use a date literal (rather than trying to convert from a string):

```
case
when ren.return_date IS NULL
THEN ROUND(DATE '2009-12-01'-ren.rent_date) 
ELSE ROUND(ren.return_date-ren.rent_date)
END AS delay_weeks,
```

Then you can simplify it by using the `COALESCE` function rather than a `CASE` expression:

```
ROUND(COALESCE(ren.return_date, DATE '2009-12-01') - ren.rent_date)
  AS delay_weeks,
```

Then, when you subtract two dates you get the difference in days (rather than weeks) so you need to divide by 7:

```sql
SELECT mem.member_id AS member_id, 
       ren.rental_id AS rental_transaction_id,
       ROUND((COALESCE(ren.return_date, DATE '2009-12-01') - ren.rent_date)/7)
         AS delay_weeks, 
       CASE
       WHEN ren.return_date IS NULL
       THEN 'not return'
       ELSE 'return'
       END AS status
FROM   members mem
       JOIN rental ren ON mem.member_id = ren.member_id
order BY member_id;
```

If you want to count only full weeks then you want to use `FLOOR`. If you want to count part weeks then you want to use `CEIL` and if you want to count to the nearest week then use `ROUND`. I'm assuming that you would want either `FLOOR` or `CEIL` instead of `ROUND` but the question isn't clear on that requirement.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4b4576b823eaecd5edbc02673fbb757d)*